# php ajax prevent default

Tags: php, ajax

A have following code:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    print("<a href=\"add-to-cart.php?uuid=". $Item->PartId ."&price=". $Item->Price."\"  >Add to cart</a>");
}
```

I heard about Ajax(sending form without page reload, e.t.c)

So as you see I have link a href
to `add-to-cart.php?uuid=someID&price=someprice`
This code works, and PHP script adds to DataBase record, and navigates to this url. But I dont need to navigate to this url.
So How could I do this, executing PHP with these dynamics parameters and prevent navigating to this URL?

But how could I

Comment: How? JavaScript/Ajax. I would use jQuery for ajax because it's **much easier** to use especially for someone new to JavaScript. This is too indepth of a question for anyone to answer since you have no basis for a start.

Comment: I know how to do  Axaj call with jQuerry, but with Form submit.
$("#formid") {..}
url: 'post.php',
blabla
succes:
}
But how to do it with Link (a href..) Should I set ID for Link? I didnt find at google a response for my question. May be exist an other way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a javascript click handler to the link so that users send AJAX-request instead of navigating to the URL.

Here's a snippet using jQuery (assuming that your links have `lnk-ajax` class):

```
<script>
$(function() {
        // Send AJAX request instead of navigating to the link's URL
        $('.lnk-ajax').click(function(e) {
            var linkUrl = this.href;

            // Send AJAX request
            $.ajax(linkUrl).done(function(data) {
                    // process the result
                    // ... put your code here ...
                    alert('Success');
                });

            // Prevent default link behaviour
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```